# wordpress align a div to center

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have made a code in which `<div>` must be aligned on center. all `div` does aligns to center only in codepen but not in wordpress.so please look the code below. It must work on wordpress too.   The code is below  :-

```css
body{
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
.header{
  padding:2%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
}

.element1, .element2, .element3, .element4, .element5, .element6 {
   display: inline-block;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
   background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* IE10 */
   background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* W3C */
  border-radius:15%;
   max-height: 100px;
   width: 8%;
   font-family:"Nuntino";
   color: white;
   opacity: 0.7;
   text-align:center;
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header">
 <p>  <div id="element1" class="element1"><font  style="font-size:3vw;" size="72px"><h1>Y</h1></font></div>
  <div class="element2"><font size="72px"  style="font-size:3vw;" ><h1>O</h1></font></div>
  <div class="element3"><font size="72px"  style="font-size:3vw;" ><h1>J</h1></font></div>
 <div class="element4"><font size="72px"  style="font-size:3vw;"><h1>A</h1></font></div>
  <div class="element5"><font size="72px"  style="font-size:3vw;"><h1>N</h1></font></div>
 <div class="element6"><font size="72px" style="font-size:3vw;" ><h1>A</h1></font></div>
</div
```

Comment: and the tag must be javascript...  Java != Javascript .

Comment: the font tag is obsolete, do not use it - use css instead.  A div and a h1 cannot be child elements of a p tag

Answer (score 0):

Check That,

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element1,
.element2,
.element3,
.element4,
.element5,
.element6 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
  /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
  /* IE10 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
  /* W3C */
  border-radius: 15%;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 8%;
  font-family: "Nuntino";
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1" class="element1">
  <font style="font-size:3vw;" size="72px">
    <h1>Y</h1>
  </font>
</div>
<div class="element2">
  <font size="72px" style="font-size:3vw;">
    <h1>O</h1>
  </font>
</div>
<div class="element3">
  <font size="72px" style="font-size:3vw;">
    <h1>J</h1>
  </font>
</div>
<div class="element4">
  <font size="72px" style="font-size:3vw;">
    <h1>A</h1>
  </font>
</div>
<div class="element5">
  <font size="72px" style="font-size:3vw;">
    <h1>N</h1>
  </font>
</div>
<div class="element6">
  <font size="72px" style="font-size:3vw;">
    <h1>A</h1>
  </font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element1,
.element2,
.element3,
.element4,
.element5,
.element6 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%);
    border-radius: 15%;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 8%;
    font-family: "Nuntino";
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can apply above css Thanks